# Highcharts series label legend in one line

Tags: highcharts

I need to show highcharts api series name in one line but not able to get it correctly.[image]

When viewport width is larger then it's not an issue but on narrow width the third legend item drops to new line. Due to SVG rendering, I am not able to apply CSS into group element.

In any case **active users** just wraps to second line and I am not able to set width of parent group  element. So far I have tried all legend default options but it didn't work.

So any help would be great.

https://jsfiddle.net/h28jv3zL/

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
     legend: {
        align: "left",
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        itemWidth: 100,
        // symbolWidth: 0,
        // symbolHeight: 0,
        // symbolRadius: 0,
        verticalAlign: "top",
        layout: "horizontal",
        floating: false,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        shadow: false,
        itemStyle: {
          "fontWeight": "normal",
          "color": "#101010",
          "textOverflow": "normal",
          "width": "auto",
          "white-space": "nowrap",
          'padding-right': "10px" 
        }
      },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            fillOpacity: 0.1
        }
    },

    series: [{
          name: "Inactive Users",
          data: [10,11,12],
          color: "#D8D8D8",
          //showInLegend: false
        },    
        {
          name: "New Users",
          data: [10,11,12],
          color: "#696969",
          //showInLegend: false
        },
        {
          name: "Active Users",
          data: [10,11,12],
          color: "#202020",
          //showInLegend: false
        },]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add some logic to check the `chart.plotWidth` and base on that substract series name or hide it inside the labelFormatter callback.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/souphrg9/